# How to replace construction variables without executing the action in SCons?

Tags: scons

I have the following action:

```
act = SCons.Action.Action('$ACTIONVAR', 'Executing a dummy action')
env['EXTENSION'] = '.err'
env['ACTIONVAR'] = '${SOURCE.filebase}$EXTENSION'
```

I want to have the value of action var depending on different target and sources.
What I want to achieve could be similar to this:

```
obj = env.Execute(act('file.o', 'file.c'))
print 'Str: ' + str(obj) #this should print 'file.err'
```

Is it possible to get the value without executing the action ?

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for the `env.subst()` method. Please check the [MAN page](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html) for a description of its exact syntax and functionality.

Comment: Is it possible to check what builder is using a certain emitter ? I need to substitute based on the name (because based on the suffix it will be to many suffixes) of the builder and I don't want to create different emitter functions for each builder.

Comment: This is starting to sound like an XY problem. Please provide a full MWE for the actual problem that you're trying to solve, preferably in a separate question with a fitting and descriptive title.